# Static_assert/define to determine if compiler was given specific flag

Tags: c++, optimization, linker, flags, static-assert

I would like to implement something that would throw up a nice easily visible error/warning when someone is compiling my code with/without specific compiler flag. In my case this is Whole Program Optimization /GL in visual studio. My program needs to always be compiled with this flag turned OFF so I want to make something like `static_assert` that would never allow people to compile this code with /GL flag set.

Does anyone know how to do this in Visual Studio?

Does anyone know how to do this platform independently?

Comment: You could check for different behaviour caused by the flag by using some assertions in your implementation.

Comment: How do I do it? My problem is that I have 2 structs of the same type, both initialized with same data and both static constexpr. Now this /GL flag optimizes those structs so they end up being only 1 struct in .rdata instead of 2. I need those data to be 2 separate entities.

Comment: Why do they need to be two separate instances?  You shouldn't need them to be and if you do it sounds like you have undefined behavior in your code.

Comment: Due to its nature my program has to fullfil various conditions regarding how it looks like in assembly.

Comment: Why is it not possible? It should be trivial to implement. Compiler knows well enough what kind of flags he was given and he can check it during compiling.